# Custom SDK - API level

Tags: android, android-source

I've build a custom Android SDK off the master branch (8.1.x) successfully, but the SDK manager shows its API level as Q.
I've tried setting `PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION` in `./build/make/core/version_defaults.mk` to several values (28, 50, etc.), but its still listed as Q.

This is an issue, since I can't specify `compileSdkVersion Q` in the gradle files.

I build the SDK by:

```
$lunch sdk-eng
$make update-api 
$make sdk
```

I use the custom build SDK by unpacking the resulting zip file to the filesystem, and specifying it in `local.properties`.

Is this really the best way to use a custom SDK?
How do I change the api level number?

Answer (score 1):

Set PLATFORM_VERSION.OPM1 ("OPM1" in my case it could be another number) as 8.1.x and PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION as 27 or other number.
follow this [format](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-vts-8.1_r4/core/version_defaults.mk)

Comment: I've done that, it lists it as android 8.1.x in the SDK manager, which still isn't right.

Comment: use this version 8.1.0